# async await methods don't work parallel on calling controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

i have a simple controller with two methods Index and IndexAsync synchronous and asynchronous  respectively. I try to do same as written in this [article](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-async-and-await-in-asp-net-what-do-these-keywords-mean/). But something going wrong , instead of 5 seconds result i get 12. How come , what's the reason ?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> IndexAsync()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        await Delay(3);
        await Delay(5);
        await Delay(4);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        return stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
    }


    private async Task<Int32> Delay(int sec)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000 * sec);
        return sec;
    }

}
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: That's bound to happen as you are making async calls one after another using await, which will make it 3 + 4 + 5 = 12 sec result

Comment: What you need is `Task.WhenAll`, to make it happen in 5 sec

Comment: Note that the code you've linked to *separately* called the methods that include the delays and *then* `await`ed the results.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i try to follow approach used in this [article](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-async-and-await-in-asp-net-what-do-these-keywords-mean/) .could you explain, what is the difference between my code and article code ?

Comment: `var contentTask = service.GetContentAsync();` - calls `GetContentAsync` and returns whilst that is in progress. Then then *start* two other async actions by calling other async methods and only *after* that point do they write `await contentTask`. Whereas you *immediately* `await` each of your async method calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article, the code *starts all three tasks* and then *awaits all three tasks*:

```
var contentTask = service.GetContentAsync(); // start task 1
var countTask = service.GetCountAsync();
var nameTask = service.GetNameAsync();

var content = await contentTask; // wait until task 1 is finished
var count = await countTask;
var name = await nameTask;
```

Your code *starts and awaits each task in turn*:

```
await Delay(3); // start task 1 and wait until it is finished
await Delay(5);
await Delay(4);
```

Answer (score 4):

Many people have a bad model in their heads of what `await` does. Despite it's name, they somehow come to believe that it *starts* things happening. Nothing could be further from the truth<sup>1</sup>.

`await` has some expression on its right-hand side. It doesn't care what that expression is, how it goes about its work, etc. All it cares about is that the expression is going to produce something that is *awaitable*<sup>2</sup>. By far the most common awaitables you'll encounter are `Task` and `Task<T>`.

And then `await` does its simple job - is this awaitable thing *finished*? If so, we'll get the result (if any) and then carry on. *If not*, then we can't make any further progress. If someone else can make good use of our thread in the meantime, we'll let that happen. And when that awaitable thing does finish, we've arranged to *resume* execution of the method containing the `await`.

---

I will just reiterate - `await` doesn't care *how* or *why* that awaitable got created. That's someone else's job - here, it's being done by the `async` machinery that transformed your `Delay` method. But `await` doesn't care that that method is marked `async` (that's an *implementation* detail of that method, not part of its signature, despite where it appears), just that it promises to return a "hot" `Task` - one that's already running.

---

<sup>1</sup>I think it's mostly because some people have learned the approximate equality `async ≅ parallelism ≅ using threads`. It was never really true but this is what we're constantly fighting to correct. And so they think "`async` must mean we're creating threads"

<sup>2</sup>Indeed, in the article you linked to, and the issue already addressed by [`Rawling`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872032/15498) the expressions *there* referred to variables that had previously been initialized by calls to `Task`-returning methods. Which is what made your own code different.

Comment: thanks, this is very valuable remark regarding await operator

Answer (score 0):

Make the following code modification, for the Async calls to be executed together not one after another :

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(Delay(3),Delay(4),Delay(5));
```

`Task.WhenAll` will provide the representative `Task`, which will finish, when all the tasks in the collection supplied are finished execution (Success / Failure). So we just `await` the representative `task` and get the necessary behavior, though it still may not guarantee 5 sec as expected. `result` will be an `int[]`, which will contain value from each call to Delay method.

In your case, the `Delay` method takes the responsibility of beginning the Task, using `await Task.Delay(1000 * sec);`, therefore if you just call the `Delay` as shown by the accepted answer, then separately `await`, then they still get executed in parallel, but let's assume, you are not sure or the Delay method is as follows:

```
private Task Delay(int sec)
{
  return Task.Delay(1000 * sec);
}
```

then using `await Task.WhenAll(...)` becomes important, since it will start the tasks which are not started, otherwise will simply wait for them to finish. Otherwise using the accepted answer you will not receive the benefit.

---

More regarding `await` as general information, from the C# 6.0 specification guide:

### Awaitable expressions

The task of an await expression is required to be awaitable. An expression t is awaitable if one of the following holds:

- t is of compile time type dynamic
- t has an accessible instance or extension method called `GetAwaiter` with no parameters and no type parameters, and a return type A for which all of the following hold:

  - A implements the interface `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion` (hereafter known as
    `INotifyCompletion` for brevity)
  - A has an accessible, readable instance property IsCompleted of type bool
  - A has an accessible instance method GetResult with no parameters and no type parameters.

The purpose of the `GetAwaiter` method is to obtain an awaiter for the task. The type A is called the awaiter type for the await expression.

The purpose of the `IsCompleted` property is to determine if the task is already complete. If so, there is no need to suspend evaluation.

The purpose of the `INotifyCompletion.OnCompleted` method is to sign up a "continuation" to the task; i.e. a delegate (of type `System.Action` ) that will be invoked once the task is complete.

The purpose of the GetResult method is to obtain the outcome of the task once it is complete.

This outcome may be successful completion, possibly with a result value, or it may be an exception which is thrown by the GetResult method.

---

### Classification of await expressions

The expression `await t` is classified the same way as the expression `(t).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` . Thus, if the return type of `GetResult is void`, the `await_expression` is classified as nothing. If it has a `non-void return type T` , the `await_expression` is classified as a value of type `T`.

---

### Runtime evaluation of await expressions

At runtime, the expression await t is evaluated as follows:

- An awaiter a is obtained by evaluating the expression `(t).GetAwaiter()`
- A bool b is obtained by evaluating the expression (a).IsCompleted
- If b is false then evaluation depends on whether a implements the interface
  `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ICriticalNotifyCompletion` (hereafter known as `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` for brevity). This check is done at binding time; i.e. at runtime if a has the compile time type dynamic , and at compile time otherwise. Let r denote the resumption delegate (Iterators):

  - If a does not implement `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` , then the expression
    `(a as (INotifyCompletion)).OnCompleted(r)` is evaluated.
  - If a does implement ICriticalNotifyCompletion , then the expression
    `(a as (ICriticalNotifyCompletion)).UnsafeOnCompleted(r)` is evaluated.
  - Evaluation is then suspended, and control is returned to the current caller of the async function.
- Either immediately after `(if b was true )`, or upon later invocation of the resumption delegate `(if b was false )`, the expression `(a).GetResult()` is evaluated. If it returns a value, that value is the result of the
  await_expression. Otherwise the result is nothing.
- An awaiter's implementation of the interface methods `INotifyCompletion.OnCompleted` and `ICriticalNotifyCompletion.UnsafeOnCompleted` should cause the delegate r to be invoked at most once. Otherwise, the behavior of the enclosing async function is undefined.

Comment: could you explain, what is the difference between my code and [article](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-async-and-await-in-asp-net-what-do-these-keywords-mean/) code

Comment: In your code it is synchronous in the sense that it will wait at each `await` statement, just that due to `await` it will not block the caller, but `Task.WhenAll` will make go together

Comment: Why you insert the tasks into a list? Simply `var result = await Task.WhenAll(Delay(3), Delay(4), Delay(5));`!

Comment: Possible to do it either way, doesn't make a difference, I wanted to make simple in the explanation

Comment: @ChayimFriedman made the change you have suggested, to make the code more crisp

Comment: @Z.R.T. check the update, provides a perspective when `Task.WhenAll` is exclusively useful

Comment: Also added more comprehensive details regarding await keyword from C# specification guide